# Why is Oracle 10g R2 V$DATABASE.NAME maximum 8 characters long?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, view

I have a database whose name contains more than eight characters, but when I run the command `SELECT name FROM V$DATABASE;` it only returns the first eight characters of what I actually named the database.

I noticed the eight-character version somewhere during the installation summary and thought this was down to a fixed table width cutting off the rest of the name, but I am getting the same using SQL*Plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database names in Oracle are limited to eight characters. If you entered more somewhere else, it has likely been truncated without notice.

As for why, presumably there was a technical reason "back in the day", and while it presumably is not an issue anymore, the limitation has been preserved for the sake of compatibility.

Comment: I assumed it was truncated for compatibility, like NetBIOS. Thankyou for your impartment.